# Treating missing pairs as zero when calculating an average in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate, missing-data

I have a table of POS Transaction data, and I'm trying to aggregate some of our purchase information. A sample might look like

```
pID (int) | pDate (varchar) | pAmount(numeric) | pCode(varchar)
1         | 01-NOV-14       | 12.67            | ELECTRONIC
2         | 01-NOV-14       | 61.89            | HOUSEWARE
3         | 01-NOV-14       | 52.25            | ELECTRONIC
4         | 02-NOV-14       | 9.12             | HOUSEWARE
5         | 02-NOV-14       | 17.11            | ELECTRONIC
6         | 03-NOV-14       | 39.88            | HOUSEWARE
7         | 03-NOV-14       | 21.60            | ELECTRONIC
8         | 03-NOV-14       | 16.78            | HOUSEWARE
9         | 04-NOV-14       | 47.29            | HOUSEWARE
```

My goal is to calculate the average daily sale amount, grouped by category. My problem is that there are an inconsistent number of sales entries per day, so I need to get the daily sum for each category before aggregating.

For this example, my goal would be a query which produces the daily average, grouped by code:

```
SalesItem  | AverageDailySales
ELECTRONIC | 25.91
HOUSEWARE  | 43.74
```

But, because not all days have sales for all categories, calculating the daily sum per category and taking the average won't work: the query

```
SELECT s.pCode AS SalesItem, TO_CHAR(AVG(s.TotalDaySales), '999.99') AS AverageDailySales 
FROM (SELECT t.pDate, t.pCode, SUM(t.pAmount) as TotalDaySales 
      FROM Pos_Transactions t 
      GROUP BY t.pDate, t.pCode) s
GROUP BY s.pCode ORDER BY s.pCode;
```

yields

```
SalesItem  | AverageDailySales
ELECTRONIC | 34.54
HOUSEWARE  | 43.74
```

which omits the fact that, on Nov 04, no electronic sales were made, and implies a higher average sale per day.

How can I deal with the missing entries when calculating with AVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is not to use `AVG`, but rather, to do the division yourself:

```
SELECT t.pCode,
       TO_CHAR(SUM(t.pAmount)
               /(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.pDate) FROM Pos_Transactions t2),
               '999.99')
       as AverageDailySales
  FROM Pos_Transactions t
 GROUP BY t.pCode
 ORDER BY t.pCode;
```

Comment: Perfect - calling distinct from a nested query fixed the issue with vkp's answer (where the group by took precendence)